# Dockerfile that Builds both ASP.NET Core and C++ binaries

Tags: c++, linux, docker, asp.net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I have the need to build both an ASP.NET Core application, which calls a C++ executable to get some work done. I have the docker file to build both images for .NET Core and C++ working great, but *separately*.

The ASP.NET Core Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4444
EXPOSE 5599
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:4444;https://+:5599

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-dotnet-configure-containers
# RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
# USER appuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["Core/Blundergat.Common/Blundergat.Common.csproj", "Core/Blundergat.Common/"]
COPY ["Core/Blundergat.Core/Blundergat.Core.csproj", "Core/Blundergat.Core/"]
COPY ["Core/Blundergat.Domain/Blundergat.Domain.csproj", "Core/Blundergat.Domain/"]
COPY ["Io/Blundergat.Io/Blundergat.Io.csproj", "Io/Blundergat.Io/"]
COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing.Generator/Blundergat.Meshing.Generator.csproj", "Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing.Generator/"]
COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing.Decimator/Blundergat.Meshing.Decimator.csproj", "Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing.Decimator/"]
COPY ["Optimization/Blundergat.Fireworks/Blundergat.Fireworks.csproj", "Optimization/Blundergat.Fireworks/"]
COPY ["Registration/Blundergat.CoarseRegistration/Blundergat.CoarseRegistration.csproj", "Registration/Blundergat.CoarseRegistration/"]
COPY ["Registration/Blundergat.FineRegistration/Blundergat.FineRegistration.csproj", "Registration/Blundergat.FineRegistration/"]
COPY ["Services/Blundergat/Blundergat.csproj", "Services/Blundergat/"]
COPY ["Storage/Blundergat.Storage/Blundergat.Storage.csproj", "Storage/Blundergat.Storage/"]
COPY ["Transport/Blundergat.Grpc/Blundergat.Grpc.csproj", "Transport/Blundergat.Grpc/"]

RUN dotnet restore "Services/Blundergat/Blundergat.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "Services/Blundergat/Blundergat.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Services/Blundergat/Blundergat.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY --from=ubuntu /src/bin/PoissonRecon .
#ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Blundergat.dll"]
ENTRYPOINT /app/Blundergat start && /bin/bash
```

This works great.

The C++ Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04 AS ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        vim g++ make

WORKDIR "/src/"

COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing/jpeg", "jpeg/"]
COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing/png", "png/"]
COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing/zlib", "zlib/"]
COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing/linux", "src/"]
COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing/Makefile", "."]

# TODO REMOVE unwanted files. 

RUN make
```

This compiles, and the executable runs fine, too.

So, I have tried to combine the two as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4444
EXPOSE 5599
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:4444;https://+:5599

FROM ubuntu:16.04 AS ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        vim g++ make

WORKDIR "/src/"

COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing/jpeg", "jpeg/"]
COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing/png", "png/"]
COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing/zlib", "zlib/"]
COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing/linux", "src/"]
COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing/Makefile", "."]

#REMOVE unwanted files. 

RUN make

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-dotnet-configure-containers
# RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
# USER appuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["Core/Blundergat.Common/Blundergat.Common.csproj", "Core/Blundergat.Common/"]
COPY ["Core/Blundergat.Core/Blundergat.Core.csproj", "Core/Blundergat.Core/"]
COPY ["Core/Blundergat.Domain/Blundergat.Domain.csproj", "Core/Blundergat.Domain/"]
COPY ["Io/Blundergat.Io/Blundergat.Io.csproj", "Io/Blundergat.Io/"]
COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing.Generator/Blundergat.Meshing.Generator.csproj", "Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing.Generator/"]
COPY ["Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing.Decimator/Blundergat.Meshing.Decimator.csproj", "Meshing/Blundergat.Meshing.Decimator/"]
COPY ["Optimization/Blundergat.Fireworks/Blundergat.Fireworks.csproj", "Optimization/Blundergat.Fireworks/"]
COPY ["Registration/Blundergat.CoarseRegistration/Blundergat.CoarseRegistration.csproj", "Registration/Blundergat.CoarseRegistration/"]
COPY ["Registration/Blundergat.FineRegistration/Blundergat.FineRegistration.csproj", "Registration/Blundergat.FineRegistration/"]
COPY ["Services/Blundergat/Blundergat.csproj", "Services/Blundergat/"]
COPY ["Storage/Blundergat.Storage/Blundergat.Storage.csproj", "Storage/Blundergat.Storage/"]
COPY ["Transport/Blundergat.Grpc/Blundergat.Grpc.csproj", "Transport/Blundergat.Grpc/"]

RUN dotnet restore "Services/Blundergat/Blundergat.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "Services/Blundergat/Blundergat.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Services/Blundergat/Blundergat.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY --from=ubuntu /src/bin/PoissonRecon .
#ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Blundergat.dll"]
ENTRYPOINT /app/Blundergat start && /bin/bash
```

This compiles the C++ and the .NET Core stuff fine.

The issue is that the base `ubuntu:16.04` image is lost, so when I attempt to run the C++ executable (that was compiled with the `-lgomp g++/gcc` option), I get the following error:

> ./PoissonRecon: error while loading shared libraries: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This is because the `/usr/lib/` folder only contains the bare minimum for the .NET assemblies.

***How can I build this Docker image so that I compile both, but keep the required C++ libraries in the `/usr/lib/` directories?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bit weird because `libgomp1` doesn't seem to be installed by default on the `ubuntu:16.04` and even after running `apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends` so there might be some difference between ubuntu 16.04 and Debian buster (10) that requires that package.

You can however install it yourself on top of your preexisting image (`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0`) with `apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgomp1`. Another options is to use the ubuntu 20.04 based one (`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal`) or check [this link](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet)  for other versions and architectures, It's possible using this image would work for the same (yet unknown) reason it works on your regular Ubuntu server.

A third and more comprehensive option is, since you know it works with your current ubuntu:16.04 image, you can install aspnet 5.0 on **it**  as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu)

**UPDATE:**

installing the missing package (`libgomp1`) on the original Debian based image fixed the issue

Comment: The last link looks promising, I will try this later and come back to you. Thanks for your answer...

Comment: The link provided in "or use the ubuntu 20.04 based one" is dead?

Comment: oh sorry put the registry pull url in the text link

Comment: did you check again since?

Comment: I have attempted to build this using Debian 10, which is what the asp net image is based on. I have not tried the results as this took sometime to build. I will come back to you…

Comment: The above - installing on Debian 10 then copying the binary to the final layer works.

Comment: That's great to hear ☺️